# Контактная форма, Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, email, form

Я начинающий в spring framework. Хочу написать контактную форму. Тоесть{Имя, Телефон, Емейл, и сообщение} например. И чтобы эти письма отправлялись на мою почту. Похожего типа штуки я уже посмотрел, например тупо отправка письма с моей почты на почту конкретного отправителя, записанного в классе(не особо разбирал его, ведь это не то что я хочу), еще делал по примеру регистрацию с  авторизацией через gmail smpt протокол, 2OAuth. Получилось. Но как сделать с thymeleaf(или чем-то еще) формочку обычную "Contact us"?
Устал искать, почти все с какими-то старыми примерами(где еще как я понял есть папка WEB-INF с xml настройками, а не аннотациями, а я учу только с аннотациями).
Кто знает может пример где найти такой формы.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Примеры со spring.io, должны быть довольно актуальными

- Просто страничка https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content
- Пример с формой https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-validating-form-input

Comment: но тут же тупо хело ворлд и форма не для почты а чисто 2 инпута:(
а мне именно нужно чтобы почту отправлять